# mule xpath expression not returning node

Tags: xpath, mule

I'm trying to use xpath in a Mule flow to select the attribute 'value' under element Host based on the current value of element Stage (which will be in a Mule variable)

Here's the XML resource file feedHosts.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <FeedHosts xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/">
         <Host value="host1.com">
             <Stage>qa</Stage>
         </Host>
         <Host value="host2.com">
             <Stage>dev</Stage>
         </Host>
         <Host value="host3.com">
              <Stage>live</Stage>
         </Host>
     </FeedHosts>
```

I've tried a few things like

```
    <set-payload value="#[groovy: getClass().getResourceAsStream('/feedHosts.xml')]" doc:name="Set Payload to feedHosts.xml"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <mulexml:xpath-extractor-transformer name="whatever" expression="/FeedHosts/Host[Stage='#[flowVars.stage]']" resultType="NODE"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

This does load feedHosts.xml into the payload but the xpath-extractor-transformer itself returns a null payload. Obviously it won't return the value attribute I want.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does `<logger message="#[flowVars.stage]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` output?

Comment: #[flowVars.stage] is the string 'qa'

Answer (score 2):

An XPath location path contains several steps which provide context. The last one selects data.

The *last* step of your expression selects a set of *all `Host` elements* in the context of `/FeedHosts`. The predicate restricts that set to the ones that have a `Stage` child element containing the text returned by `#[flowVars.stage]`.

I'm not familiar with the *Mule* variable interpolation syntax. *Assuming* that the value `#[flowVars.stage]` *actually produces* one of the strings `qa`, `dev` or `live`, it should select one of the `Host` elements.

But you said you actually want to *"select **the attribute 'value'** under element Host based on the current value of element Stage"*. In this case the last step should be in the *attribute axis*, and the `Hosts` set is only your *context*. You need to add one extra step:

```
/FeedHosts/Host[Stage=#[flowVars.stage]]/@value
```

For the interpolation syntax above, I referred to [this reference](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/dynamic_xpath_values_in_evaluator_using_mel)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how *Mule* interpolates variables. I assumed `#[...]` worked that way. Where does `flowVars.stage` come from? Would it be something like `#[/FeedHosts/Host[Stage=flowVars.stage]]/@value]`, or perhaps there is some syntax to pass parameters to expressions.

Comment: Reading the examples [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Examples)  (see section 5 - Using XPath), it seems that you have to assign the individual XPath expressions to your mule variable, so when you get the variable, your XPath expressions are performed

Comment: It seems that Mule doesn't support string interpolation, but it seems it should in XPath expressions. So there are two alternatives: 1) If it does, you could try removing the apostrophes: `/FeedHosts/Host[Stage=#[flowVars.stage]]/@value`. 2) If that doesn't work, you might be able to use string concatenation instead: `"/FeedHosts/Host[Stage='&quot; + flowVars.stage + &quot;']/@value"`. Unfortunately I can't test that here now. If any of those solutions work, tell me and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I got the information about the *concatenation* strategy from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17866136/3190413)

Comment: I would give one last try using `[Stage=' + flowVars.stage + ']` (I got it from the other answer, but I don't really understand why the `&quot;`

Comment: Doesn't work.  I'll be talking to a Mulesoft guy tomorrow and will post a solution hopefully. Funny how the Mulesoft docs don't have a single example of an xpath expression built from variables, which is the most common use case.

Answer (score 0):

This example returns the desired node and attribute (thanks helderdarocha) and also executes the query via an expression-transformer.  The xpath-extractor-transformer expression won't accept the # character but expression-transformer will.

```
<set-payload value="#[groovy: getClass().getResourceAsStream('/hostsfile.xml')]" />
<set-variable variableName="myXPath" value="/FeedHosts/Host[Stage='#[stage]']/@value" />

<enricher target="#[flowVars.host]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
     <expression-transformer expression="#[xpath(myXPath).value]" />
</enricher>

<logger message="host is #[host]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you XML has namespace associated with it, so you need to use Mule namespace manger to extract the values using Xpath
https://developer.mulesoft.com/
docs/display/current/XML+Namespaces
Something like the following :-

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
   <mulexml:namespace prefix="foo" uri="http://www.foo.org/"/>
   <mulexml:namespace prefix="bar" uri="http://www.bar.org"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Then you can get the values in your Xpath,
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XML+Module+Reference